# CMake: file copy is not overwritting existing files

Tags: cmake

I want to copy certain files to a folder and then overwrite some of them. But it seems `file(COPY ..)` is not overwriting existing files.
Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/common/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tmp/ FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.xml")

if(MY_OPTION)
    file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/custom/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tmp/ FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.xml")
```

I can swap the above lines - first copy `custom` and then `common` at which point copy of `common` will not overwrite the existing from `custom`.
This works fine but it's a bit obfuscated and I'm searching for a better solution (with copy/install and not custom command).

I don't see any option to explicitly overwrite...
`file(COPY_FILE ...)` is an option but I don't want to specify each file...

Edit: from Tsyvarev comment - it's probably related to same timestamps for files. Unfortunately I'm stuck with same timestamps.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#copy) of `file(COPY)` command: "Copying preserves input file timestamps, and optimizes out a file if it exists at the destination with the same timestamp.". That is, copying is not performed if a destination file has the same timestamp as a source one.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I guess that's the problem but I'm stuck with same timestamps.

Comment: One option would be to use a custom command calling `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ...` AFAIK this will unconditionally copy files. Edit: just read you're not interested in a custom command solution. I'll leave the comment around but feel free to ignore :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already found out, there's no option in `file(COPY ...)` to force the operation. Also, it will not overwrite files with the same (or newer, I think) timestamps, see [CMake doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#copy).

The newer `file(COPY_FILE ...)` on the other hand will overwrite existing files if not called with the `ONLY_IF_DIFFERENT` flag. To avoid enumerating all the XML files in CMakeLists.txt, we can glob them and let CMake loop over all XML files. This is not different from specifying `FILES_MATCHING PATTERN`.

Here's the sample code:

```
# Create target dir if it does not already exist
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/tmp)

# Existing line, copy everything from common
file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/common/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tmp/ FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.xml")

# Glob all XML files in custom
file(GLOB xml_files custom/*.xml)
# Loop over all the XML files that were found
foreach(in_file IN LISTS xml_files)
    # Get just the file name, w/o path
    get_filename_component(out_file ${in_file} NAME)
    # Do the actual copy
    file(COPY_FILE ${in_file} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/tmp/${out_file})
endforeach()
```

The other way to do it would be to just swap the two lines and add a comment that CMake won't overwrite existing files. You already wrote that in your question and I think it may already be the most elegant solution.

Comment: At the bottom of COPY_FILE there's mentioned also `configure_file()`:

    An important difference is that `configure_file()` creates a dependency on the source file, so CMake will be re-run if it changes. The `file(COPY_FILE)` sub-command does not create such a dependency.

Probably depending on context, this can be used too? Or is it bad decision?

Comment: @RyoidenshiAokigahara I think it depends on the context, as you write. OP depends on option `MY_OPTION` to copy custom XML files so it looked like a configuration-time decision. OP also stated to be stuck with the timestamps so I assumed them not to change. Because of the slight differences in semantics, I'd rather go with `file(COPY)` for static configuration files.